# Restriction in the trigonometric identity of $\tan 3x$

Tags: trigonometry

In the text book, the following identity is given:
$$\tan 3x=\frac{3\tan x - \tan^3x}{1-3\tan^2x}$$
Below it is written: $3x$ should not be equal to $(n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})$.
My view point is that, both $3x$ and $x$ should not be equal to $(n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})$. Because, $\tan x$ is present  on the right side.
So why is it that only the restriction for $3x$ is mentioned in the text book. Please give the reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $x=n\pi+\pi/2.$ Then it follows that $3x=(3n+1)\pi+\pi/2.$ So the restriction on $x$ is already implied by the restriction on $3x.$

Comment: But $3x=n\pi+\pi/2$ implies $x=n/3\pi+\pi/6$, which is not of the form $n\pi+\pi/2$ as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Wolfuryo The thing is that $3x$ cannot be of the form $n\pi+\pi/2$ for *any* integer $n$. Consider the case when $n$ is of the form $3m+1$ for an arbitrary integer $m$.

Comment: I understand it now. If $x$ is of the form, than $3x$ is of that form too, so the condition for $3x$ is enough. Thanks!